# Python Regex - Split string after every character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that follows the pattern of a `1+` numbers followed by a single letter, `'a', 'b', 'c'`. I want to split the string after every letter.

```
some_function('12a44b65c')
>>> ['12a', '44b', '65c']
```

[image]

I've tried so far

```
re.split('([abc]\d+)', '12a44b65c')
>>> ['12', 'a44', '', 'b65', 'c']
```

Comment: Try swapping the patterns: `re.findall(r'\d+[abc]', '12a44b65c')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is backwards - it should be any number of digits followed by an `a`, `b` or a `c`. additionally, I wouldn't use `split`, which returns annoying empty strings, but [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> re.findall('(\d+[abc])', '12a44b65c')
['12a', '44b', '65c']
```

Comment: \d* will also match with no digits given. You have to use \d+ to meet the 1+ digits requirement.

Comment: Besides, there is no need in the capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use the [**newer regex module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can even split on zero-width matches (with lookarounds, that is).

```
import regex as re

rx = r'(?V1)(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)'
string = "12a44b65c"
parts = re.split(rx, string)
print parts
# ['12a', '44b', '65c']
```

This approach looks for one of `a-z` behind and a digit (`\d`) immediately ahead.
The original `re.split()` does not allow zero-width matches, for compatibility you explicitely need to turn the new behaviour on with `(?V1)` in the pattern.
See a [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sO4kQ3/1).